# ajax + rails - post data value disappearing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am working on a rails app. I have some JS data i'm sending to rails. The problem is, one of my values in my ajax request is not present in rails' `params` by the time it makes it from the JS to the controller.

First, what's triggering it is this top level

```
if (prospects.length > 0) {
  _self.sendData(prospects);
} else {
  alert('must submit more than 1 prospect');
}
```

that function looks like this

```
sendData: function(prospects) {
    var prospects = prospects;
    var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
    var team_id = $('#team_id').val();

    var data = {
      prospects: prospects,
      user_id: user_id,
      team_id: team_id
    }

    // data looks like (from chrome console)
   // {prospects: Array(2), user_id: "950", team_id: ""}    

    $.ajax({
      url: '/path/to/url/',
      type: 'PUT',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('success from sendData!');
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log('error from sendData');
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
```

In this function above, I see all of my values present. So next, is the rails controller

```
def process
    p '*' * 100
    p params
    p '*' * 100
end
```

the output of these `p` statements are
"****************************************************************************************************"
{"user_id"=>"950", "team_id"=>"", "action"=>"method_name", "controller"=>"name/of/controller"}
"****************************************************************************************************"

As you can see, `params[:prospects]` is nil! I do not see my mistake and have no idea why that value isn't making it to the controller.

Does anyone see why `params[:prospects]` isn't present?

**UPDATE**

I was able to get it working by wrapping the `$.ajax` data inside of jQuery's [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) function. My working function looks like this

```
sendData: function(prospects) {
        var prospects = prospects;
        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
        var team_id = $('#team_id').val();

        var data = {
          prospects: prospects,
          user_id: user_id,
          team_id: team_id
        }

        var json_data = $.param(data);  

        $.ajax({
          url: '/path/to/url/',
          type: 'PUT',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: json_data,
          success: function(data) {
            console.log('success from sendData!');
            console.log(data);
          },
          error: function(error) {
            console.log('error from sendData');
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: try to convert the data to string format using `JSON.stringify()` and see if that helps

Comment: @Subash thanks for the answer. I think a variation of this is needed (but i can't seem to find any docs to support that). In the `$.ajax` call, changing `data: data` to `data: JSON.stringify(data)` does add `prospects` to `params` but combines all of the data into 1 key. it outputs it malformed like this: `{"{\"prospects\":"=>{"{},{}"=>{",\"user_id\":\"950\",\"team_id\":\"\"}"=>nil}}`. any suggestions? i'm almost positive i've done something like this before and it didn't require this level of effort to sanitize params (maybe different now because it's an array of objects)

Comment: what value does `prospects` hold?

Comment: @Subash in the example i provided above, `prospects` would be an array of JS objects.

Comment: do those JS objects represent model objects, if yes then you can just pass in `ids` and retrieve them in the backend  to reduce the complexity

Comment: @Subash love that idea, but unfortunately they are not; they are pure JS objects coming from an API i'm using

Comment: @Subash I was able to figure it out by taking my array of javascript objects, and calling [`$.param(prospects)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) on it before `$.ajax` submission. On rails I just called `JSON.parse(params[:prospects])` and its working fine for now

Comment: Why don't you sprint prospects above _self.sendData(prospects) line to check the value?

Answer (score 0):

Confusingly, the `dataType` option for `$.ajax` doesn't set the type of the data object. It sets the type of what is expected in the server response. Therefore, you have to add:

```
...
data: JSON.stringify({yada: 'yada'})
contentType: 'application/json'
...
```

Rails will pick that up and give you what you expect via the `params` function.

I hope that helps.